# Image corrupted while uploading to S3 bucket using laravel image intervention

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Here is my code. I'm trying to upload an image to S3, but its corrupting how Can i solve this issue ? [image]

```
public static function putFile($filePath, $fileName, $file, $fileOptions)
{
    $sizeArray = $fileOptions['sizeArray'] ?? [1400, 1400];
    $extension = $fileOptions['extention'] ?? 'jpg';
    
    $imageFile = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
    $imageFile->resize($sizeArray[0], $sizeArray[1], function ($constraint) {
       $constraint->aspectRatio();
    });
    
    Storage::cloud()->put($filePath . "/" . $fileName, (string) $imageFile->encode($extension, 80));
    
    Storage::cloud()->setVisibility($filePath . "/" . $fileName, 'public');
    CDN::invalidateByFilePath($filePath . "/" . $fileName);
    return;
}
```

filesystem.php

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key'    => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: are you using "Imagick" or "GD" as your image intervention driver ? have you tried the other one ? (you can find it in config/image.php  @ 'driver' => ). Your error mostly has nothing to do with the storage driver or amazon-s3

Comment: Comment the image manipulation codes and check whether the image uploads correctly or not.

Comment: I'm using "Imagick". image is uploading properly on local. Only issue with the live server.